# can't modify category after copying the remote Magento site to local

Tags: magento

I copied the files and Magento site includes the files and database to localhost, but after that, when i add/modify categories, the web got freezes and the ajax overlay "please wait" stay forever, and i'need to restart the Apache (xampp) to release it. Anyone know what are the problems?

https://www.google.com.hk/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=O-MTU9yQN-GPiAeTtYGgAw&gws_rd=cr#q=magento+add+category+please+wait

I searched around the internet and same issue has been occurred before. But I can't figure out the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all the log files on your localhost:

```
C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log, 
C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log,
C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql_error.log
```

Then you might need to change some of the mysql, php or apache settings. In particular maximum PHP script execution time. Feel free to post the errors here and someone may be able to help. I think your database is running too slowly or using up all the memory and the knock-on effect is Apache needing to be restarted.